# SQL Where clause Coalese vs ISNULL VS Dynamic

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a question for best use when creating where clause in a SQL Procedure.
I have written a query three different ways one using Coalesce in where clause, one using a isnull or statement, and one which is dynamic using sp_executesql.

Coalesce:

```
WHERE       ClientID = COALESCE(@Client, ClientID)  AND 
            AccessPersonID = COALESCE(@AccessPerson, AccessPersonID)
```

IsNull Or:

```
WHERE       (@Client IS NULL OR @Client = ClientID) 
            AND (@AccessPerson IS NULL OR @AccessPerson= AccessPersonID)
```

and dynamically:

```
SET @sql = @sql  + Char(13) + Char(10) + N'WHERE   1 = 1';

    IF @Client <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + Char(13) + Char(10) + N' AND ClientID = @Client '
        END

    IF @AccessPerson <> 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql  + Char(13) + Char(10) + N' AND AccessPersonID = @AccessPerson '
        END
```

When I use SQL Sentry Plan Explorer the results show for the estimated that the Coalesce is the best but the the lest accurate between estimated and actual.  Where the dynamic has the worst estimated but it is 100% accurate to the actual.

This is a very simple procedure I am just trying to figure out what is the bes way to write procedures like this.  I would thin the dynamic is the way to go since it is the most accurate.

Comment: In order to get a good answer, you'll need to define, "Best".  As it is currently written, the question is open-ended and asking for opinions on which is better.  (Something that StackOverflow doesn't like.)  But if you can define what you want and modify the question to be objective rather than subjective, you might get the answers that you're looking for.

Comment: "Most Accurate" depends on what you're trying to get back. All 3 of these will return "accurate" info with the same non-null inputs. But each query does something slightly different with either input as NULL, and the dynamic SQL version is more difficult to read. With NULL inputs, the top 2 are probably "most accurate" from a SQL functioning viewpoint, but the last one does what you're asking kinda by accident. You can't compare NULL, so your query is essentially WHERE 1=1 with no compare for ClientID or APID. #2 is WHERE TRUE AND TRUE and #1 is WHERE ClientID = ClientID and APID = APID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is the 'dynamic' option. It's good you left parameters in because it protects against SQL Injection (at this layer anyway).

The reason 'dynamic' is the best is because it will create a query plan that is best for the given query. With your example you might get up to 3 plans for this query, depending on which parameters are > 0, but each plan generated one will be optimized for that scenario (they will leave out unnecessary parameter comparisons).

The other two styles will generate one plan (each), and it will only be optimized for the parameters you used AT THAT TIME ONLY. Each subsequent execution will use the old plan and might be cached using the parameter you are not calling with.

'Dynamic' is not as clean-code as the other two options, but for performance, it will give you the optimal query plan each time.

Comment: Dynamic SQL isn't necessarily always the answer. It's possible to protect against SQL injection through the other methods - especially if he's already running this in a sproc. The bigger issue is that those 3 queries don't do quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

And the dynamic SQL operates in a different scope than your sproc will, so even though you declare a variable in your sproc, you'll have to redeclare it in your dynamic SQL. Or concat it into the statement. But then you *should* also do NULL checks in your dynamic SQL AND in your sproc, because NULL isn't equal to 0 nor is it not equal to 0. You can't compare it because it doesn't exist. :-S

```
DECLARE @Client int = 1 
  ,  @AccessPerson int = NULL
;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000) = N'SELECT * FROM ##TestClientID WHERE 1=1'
;
IF @Client <> 0
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, N' AND ClientID = ', CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @Client))
  END
;
IF @AccessPerson <> 0
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, N' AND AccessPersonID =', CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @AccessPerson))
  END
;   

PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sql
```

Note: For demo purposes, I also had to modify my temp table above and make it a global temp instead of a local temp, since I'm calling it from dynamic SQL. It exists in a different scope. Don't forget to clean it up after you're done. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your top two statements don't do quite the same things if either value is NULL.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0aa3/4

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb..#TestClientID', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TestClientID;
GO


CREATE TABLE #TestClientID ( ClientID int , AccessPersonID int )

INSERT INTO #TestClientID (ClientID, AccessPersonID)
SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 0,0


DECLARE @ClientID int = NULL
DECLARE @AccessPersonID int = 1

SELECT * FROM #TestClientID
WHERE ClientID = COALESCE(@ClientID, ClientID)  
    AND AccessPersonID = COALESCE(@AccessPersonID, AccessPersonID)

SELECT * FROM #TestClientID
WHERE (@ClientID IS NULL OR @ClientID = ClientID) 
      AND (@AccessPersonID IS NULL OR @AccessPersonID = AccessPersonID)
```

That said, if you're looking to eliminate a NULL input value, then use the COALESCE(). NULLs can get weird when doing comparisons. COALESCE(a,b) is more akin to MS SQL's ISNULL(a,b). In other words, if a IS NULL, use b.

And again, it really all depends on what you're ultimately trying to do. sp_ExecuteSQL is MS-centric, so if you don't plan to port this to any other database, you can use that. But honestly, in 15 years I've probably ported an application from one db to another fewer than a dozen times. It's more important if you're writing an application that will be used by other people who will install it on different systems, but if it's an enclosed system, the benefits of the database you're using usually outweigh the lack of portability.

Comment: Also, the CRLFs in your dynamic SQL aren't needed. I'd get rid of them and only include anything you actually need for the query. Plus they dynamic SQL doesn't filter on a variable if it's NULL. IF that's what you want, then don't default them with a COALESCE() or ISNULL(). Also, @ Client <> 0 is "technically" invalid when @ Client = NULL, however, SQL will still ignore that block because you can't compare NULL to a value.

Comment: While I agree the the ISNULL version looks and everything leads you to believe that it is not correct I have tested all three ways now with 7 different queries, different table, but the results always match.

Comment: The results might match, but ISNULL(x,y) and COALESCE(x,y) are different than x IS NULL OR y. And the results will match if both inputs are non-NULL. But if either of those inputs are NULL, then you will get an extra record. Look at the Fiddle I posted above. In a SQL sense, those two WHERE statements behave slightly differently. When testing, go after edge-cases as well to see if your code still behaves the same with odd data.

Comment: Sorry, looking at your 3 WHEREs, it seems that you don't want to do a comparison if the input value is NULL. So with @ ClientID = NULL then you would get WHERE ClientID = ClientID for the COALESCE, generating a comparison essentially of every row = itself. WHERE (@ ClientID IS NULL OR @ ClientID = ClientID) would evaluate to WHERE TRUE because @ ClientID IS NULL is TRUE and it wouldn't go to @ ClientID = ClientID, so no comparison.

Comment: The Dynamic SQL would not generate a comparison, but only because @ ClientID <> 0 can't be evaluated when @ ClientID is NULL, so it would ignore that block, but not for the reason you intended. NULLs just work weird sometimes. It all really depends on what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have included One more section of the query

For the ISNULL and the COALESCE I am converting a value of 0 to null where in the dynamic I am leaving the value as 0 for the if clause.  That is why the look a bit different.

From what I have been seeing the the COALESCE seems to be the consistently the worst performing. 
Surprisingly from what I have tested the ISNULL and dynamic are very similar with the ISNULL version being slightly better in most cases.

In most cases it has reviled indexes that needed to be add and in most cases the indexes improved the queries the most but after thet have been added the ISNULL and Dynamic still perform better than the COALESCE.

Also I can not see us switching from MSSQL in the near or distant future.